# How to persist an R workspace across multiple CMD statements in a Dockerfile?

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, persistence, interactive

I am creating a docker container to accept input data from a client and then source an R script that runs an analysis on the given data and outputs three plots as PDFs to the working directory.  I am running into the issue of needing two CMD statements in the Dockerfile which is not allowed by the Docker Engine.  I need the reading of the user's data to occur at run time so the data set can be changed depending on the user. The R script then needs to be sourced after the user's data has been read in as a table object in the R workspace.  What happens is, the data reads in just fine but an error message indicates that the second CMD line, to source the R script, can't find the data that has just been read in.  I understand this is because each line of the Dockerfile is executed separately on build, but I don't know how to fix this.  I've researched volumes, the use of supervisor, and the possibility of using multiple containers.  I could also possibly make a Python script to dynamically program my R script but that may still need two CMD lines.  I have yet to find an example specific enough to my situation.  How would any of you solve this?

Here is my R script to create 3 plots from a data frame 'x':

```
library(iq)
norm_data <- iq::preprocess(x, median_normalization = FALSE, pdf_out = NULL)
protein_list <- iq::create_protein_list(norm_data)

# basic protein plot
pdf(file = "Protein P00366.pdf")
iq::plot_protein(protein_list$P00366, main = "Protein P00366", split = NULL)
dev.off()

protein_table <- iq::create_protein_table(protein_list)

#MaxLFQ plot
pdf(file = "MaxLFQ quantification of P00366.pdf")
iq::plot_protein(rbind(protein_list$P00366, 
                       MaxLFQ = iq::maxLFQ(protein_list$P00366)$estimate), 
                 main = "MaxLFQ quantification of P00366", 
                 col = c(rep("gray", nrow(protein_list$P00366)), "green"), 
                 split = NULL)  
dev.off()

# ground truth
MaxLFQ_estimate <- iq::maxLFQ(protein_list$P12799)$estimate

ground_truth <-  log2(rep(c(200, 125.99, 79.37, 50, 4, 2.52, 1.59, 1), each = 3))
ground_truth <- ground_truth - mean(ground_truth) + mean(MaxLFQ_estimate)

#ground truth plot
pdf(file = "P12799 MaxLFQ versus groundtruth.pdf")
iq::plot_protein(rbind(MaxLFQ = MaxLFQ_estimate,
                       Groundtruth = ground_truth), 
                 main = "P12799 - MaxLFQ versus groundtruth",  
                 split = 0.75, 
                 col = c("green", "gold"))  
dev.off()
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM r-base:latest

ENV SCRIPT=""
ENV DATA=""                            

RUN R -e "install.packages('iq', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

WORKDIR /home/iq/

CMD R -e "x <- read.table(\"$DATA\", header = TRUE, sep = ",", fill = TRUE)" \
   && R -e "source('$SCRIPT')"
```

In a folder with path /home/iq, I have my script called iqTest.R, the Dockerfile, and data.csv.
I have been building and running my container with the following commands:

```
$ cd iq
$ docker build -t my_image .
$ docker run -it -v /home/user/iq:/home/iq --env DATA=data.csv --env SCRIPT=iqTest.R my_image:latest
```

After attempting to run, I get the following error message from the R workspace:

```
> source('iqTest.R')
Error in iq::preprocess(x, median_normalization = FALSE, pdf_out = NULL) : 
  object 'x' not found
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> <Anonymous>
```

Edit: I recently discovered that the problem was more R related: you can use a `;` to connect multiple lines of R code in a single line, which solves the problem with multiple CMD statements. May this serve as an example to anyone who is connecting R and Docker.
For example, the new Dockerfile with a semicolon to link lines:

```
FROM r-base:latest

ENV SCRIPT=""
ENV DATA="" 

RUN mkdir /home/analysis/

RUN R -e "install.packages('iq', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

WORKDIR /home/analysis/

CMD R -e "x = read.csv(\"$DATA\", header = TRUE, sep = ",", fill = TRUE); source('$SCRIPT')"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the data path configurable via an environment variable, then I would recommend to access that variable in your script with [`Sys.getenv()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.getenv.html). This also allows you to use `Rscript` instead of `R -e "source...`.

Here is what worked for me:

**script.R**

```
cat(Sys.getenv('SCRIPT'), '\n');
cat(Sys.getenv('DATA'), '\n')
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM r-base:latest

ENV SCRIPT="script.R"
ENV DATA="data.csv"

WORKDIR /workspace

CMD R -q -e "source('$SCRIPT')"
# alternative: CMD Rscript $SCRIPT
```

**Usage**

```
daniel@nuest /tmp/stackoverflow []$ docker build --tag stackoverflow .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/5 : FROM r-base:latest
 ---> 46edce0e80af
Step 2/5 : ENV SCRIPT="script.R"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8f26d34d9c0a
Step 3/5 : ENV DATA="data.csv"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 16c83c16a4c8
Step 4/5 : WORKDIR /workspace
 ---> Running in fce8619af30b
Removing intermediate container fce8619af30b
 ---> a8278f609d9a
Step 5/5 : CMD R -q -e "source('$SCRIPT')"
 ---> Running in 765bafeb8681
Removing intermediate container 765bafeb8681
 ---> ff7d7b09dffb
Successfully built ff7d7b09dffb
Successfully tagged stackoverflow:latest
daniel@nuest /tmp/stackoverflow []$ docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/workspace stackoverflow
> source('script.R')
script.R 
data.csv 
> 
>
```

---

Alternatively, you could try passing the data path as an argument to your script file, see https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/05-cmdline/

As an aside: It is better to pin a specific R version than to use `:latest`, for reproducibility.